# ReactJS + Tracker: Update parent state

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-tracker

I'm having an issue with autorun and setting the state of a parent. For example, I'm having cateogry items which also have subcat items:

1. Category A

   - Sub 1
   - Sub 2
2. Category B

   - Sub 3
   - Sub 4

Now, if I visit Sub 4, the state of Category B and Sub 4 should be go to active.

In my sub component, my code looks like this:

```
export class CategorySubItem extends Tracker.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        active: false
    };

    this.autorun(() => {
        if(LayoutGlobals.get().categoryId == this.props.doc.id) {
            this.setState({active:true});
            this.props.parent.setState({active:true});
        } else {
            this.setState({active:false});
            this.props.parent.setState({active:false});
        }
    });




}
```

Calling an sub category item:

```
<CategorySubItem doc={cat} key={cat.id} parent={this}/>
```

LayoutGlobals is a reactive variable. When I set the state of my parent, I'm ending up in an infinite loops of rerenders. What would be the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Components should only be responsible for themselves and delegate actions to their children. Never flow back up the tree to a parent

Answer (score 1):

Never set the state of a parent component. All components should only set their own state instead. Write a function for your `Category` component do decide whether it's active or not.

I'd try to avoid `autorun` though. Just pass `LayoutGlobals.get().categoryId` as a prop down the component tree, and implement your own [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) function. That way you allow React to minimize re-evaluation.

Comment: But im working with FlowRouter and need to listen for url changes? Don't I need in this case an autorun function to listen for changes? My idea is to implement this function within the Category component and then pass active values down as prop.

Comment: Use `createComponent` to turn reactive Meteor values to React props. For example, you can call FlowRouter in your Menu component's `createComponent`, and then just pass that prop down to Categories and SubCategories.